# Restricting methods to only few classes in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a notification class, which has the interface similar to following (with some syntactical issues):

```
template<typename ...T>
Notification
{

public:
void addObserver(std::function<void (T...)> o);
void notify(T...);
};
```

Then there is a host class which acts as a notification center:

```
class NotificationCenter
{

public:
    Notification<int, int> mPointChangedNotification;
};
```

And finally, there is actual observer who listens for the notifications:

```
class Listener
{
void someFunction(int, int)
{
}

void SomeMethod(NotificationCenter &m)
{
m.mPointChangedNotification.addObserver(someFunction);
}
};
```

So, far so good. But the problem is that notify function is visible even to actual observer, while it should be accessible only to the NotificationCenter class. If someone could provide help in fixing this design issue, that will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need too that much flexibility in designing your access control policy, you can simply make `NotificationCenter` a `friend` of your `Notification` class template (again, giving `notify()` private accessibility):

```
template<typename ...T>
Notification
{
public:
    void addObserver(std::function<void (T...)> o);
private:
    friend class NotificationCenter;
    void notify(T...);
};
```

This way, `NotificationCenter` would be allowed to invoke `notify()`, but all other clients will only have access to `addObserver()`.

---

If you want to allow for more flexibility, you could let `Notification` accept a further template parameter, and make the type specified in that template parameter a `friend` of `Notification`. Then, you could give `notify()` private accessibility, so that other non-`friend` class would not be able to invoke it:

```
template<typename F, typename ...T>
Notification
{
public:
    void addObserver(std::function<void (T...)> o);
private:
    friend class F;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    void notify(T...);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but if make the entire NotificationCenter a friend of Notification, then NotificationCenter will get access to all of Notification's private data. So, is there a way to restrict it member wise?

Comment: @Aarkan: Yes, it is possible. See [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t$295). In that example, I am making only one of the two member functions of `B` a `friend` of `A`, and the compiler generates an error if the non-`friend` function is trying to access `A`'s private members